# `flock` is randomly failing on desktop PC but not on notebook, could be defective hardware?

Tags: linux

I am using the below script to stress test exclusive lock with `flock`.

On my notebook, it always works fine.
But when I run it on my desktop PC, it may randomly fail, letting two instances run at the same time (acquiring the same lock!).
Both run ubuntu 20.04.

So I am suspecting a hardware problem on my desktop, may be the RAM?

So, my question is, based on the tip flock missbehavior is giving me, how can I track/determine what hardware piece is defective?
I mean, what flock does that could point what hardware is defective (or may be has low quality)?

How I confirm the problem:
I get all flock processes that have children's command matching the full path script name (that is what flock should execute as child command).
Also, I log the work done by each script, and on that log has simultaneous work of two or more of it's instances. The work logs only if the lock is acquired.
Could I not be configuring flock correctly to provide exclusive/unique locks?
I am using this on another terminal now too:
`while true;do date;lslocks |grep flock;sleep 1;done`

The script:
`cat >flock.tst.sh;chmod +x flock.tst.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8

# HELPERS:
#trash /tmp/flock.tst.log;for((i=0;i<20;i++));do flock.tst.sh&:;done #run this on shell
#pkill -fe flock.tst.sh #end all concurrent children trying to acquire the lock
#while true;do date;lslocks |grep flock;sleep 1;done #use this to check if there is more than one lock acquired, check also the log file to confirm it, and if there is two subsequent WORK on the terminal log, it means a problem happened too

: ${bDaemonizing:=false}
: ${bReport:=false} #help use this to show more log, but will be harder to read it.
: ${bCheck:=false} #help this will let the script check if there is more than one instance working, but it may be slow and make it more difficult to let the problem happen
if ! $bDaemonizing;then
  echo "this IS a daemon script, only one instace runnable"
  flSelf="`realpath $0`"
  
  #set -x 
  while ! bDaemonizing=true flock --timeout=$(bc <<< "0.2+0.0$RANDOM") "$flSelf" "$flSelf" "$@";do
    if $bCheck;then
      strParents="$(nice -n 19 pgrep -f "^flock --timeout=.* $flSelf $flSelf" |tr '\n' ',' |sed -r 's"(.*),"\1"')"
      if [[ -n "$strParents" ]];then
        anDaemonPid=( $(nice -n 19 pgrep --parent "$strParents" -f "$flSelf") )
        if((${#anDaemonPid[*]}>1));then echo "ERROR: more than one daemon, flock failed!? :(";ps --no-headers -o ppid,pid,cmd -p "${anDaemonPid[@]}";fi
        if $bReport && ((${#anDaemonPid[*]}==1));then echo "$$:Wait daemon stop running or 'kill ${anDaemonPid[0]}'";fi #could be: "already running, exiting.", but the new instance may have updated parameters that work as intended now.
      fi
    fi
  done
  
  exit #returns w/e flock does
fi

echo "$$:Work:`date`"
for((i=0;i<60;i++));do
  echo "`\
    echo $i;\
    date;\
    ps --no-headers -o ppid,pid,stat,state,pcpu,rss,cmd -p "$PPID";\
    ps --no-headers -o ppid,pid,stat,state,pcpu,rss,cmd -p "$$";\
  `" >>/tmp/flock.tst.log
  
  sleep 1
done
echo "$$:Done:`date`"
```

---

Some results:
As you can see, the exclusive lock was acquired by proccesses 1458428(flock:1458427) and 1438949(flock:1438941) simultaneously :(

The log file (created by the script) shows this problem (at second 50, happened a second 2 log of the other instance that should not have acquired the lock):

```
2
Fri 22 Jan 17:03:16 -03 2021
1438953 1458427 S    S  0.0   784 flock --timeout=.22377 /home/myUser/bin/flock.tst.sh /home/myUser/bin/flock.tst.sh
1458427 1458428 S    S  0.0  3852 /bin/bash /home/myUser/bin/flock.tst.sh
50
Fri 22 Jan 17:03:16 -03 2021
1438925 1438941 S    S  0.0   788 flock --timeout=.229687 /home/myUser/bin/flock.tst.sh /home/myUser/bin/flock.tst.sh
1438941 1438949 S    S  0.0  3900 /bin/bash /home/myUser/bin/flock.tst.sh
```

`lslock` shows this (the while with `date` is on the script as tip):

```
Fri 22 Jan 17:03:16 -03 2021
flock           1459088 FLOCK  1.8K WRITE* 0          0          0 /home/myUser/bin/flock.tst.sh
flock           1458427 FLOCK  1.8K WRITE  0          0          0 /home/myUser/bin/flock.tst.sh
flock           1438941 FLOCK  1.8K WRITE  0          0          0 /home/myUser/bin/flock.tst.sh (deleted)
Fri 22 Jan 17:03:17 -03 2021
flock           1459616 FLOCK  1.8K WRITE* 0          0          0 /home/myUser/bin/flock.tst.sh
flock           1458427 FLOCK  1.8K WRITE  0          0          0 /home/myUser/bin/flock.tst.sh
flock           1438941 FLOCK  1.8K WRITE  0          0          0 /home/myUser/bin/flock.tst.sh (deleted)
```

the terminal log (that spawned the many concurrent instances) shows this:

```
1438949:Work:Fri 22 Jan 17:02:23 -03 2021
1458428:Work:Fri 22 Jan 17:03:14 -03 2021
1438949:Done:Fri 22 Jan 17:03:26 -03 2021
1476209:Work:Fri 22 Jan 17:04:02 -03 2021
1458428:Done:Fri 22 Jan 17:04:17 -03 2021
```

Comment: How do you verify that you have two instances? Do you actually have both of them succeeding with the lock and running the "work", or do you just rely on pgrep seeing two `flock` processes on the system?

Comment: I get all flock processes that have children's command matching the full path script name (that is what flock should execute as child command). Also, I log the work done by each script, and on that log has simultaneous work of two or more of it's instances. The work happens only if the lock is acquired. Am I configuring flock correctly to provide exclusive/unique locks?

Comment: Well, keep in mind that flock running doesn't mean it has the lock already – it may be still initializing, it may be waiting for the lock timeout, or it may be about to exit... Also, while I can't look up the manual right now, I think you might need `-x` to actually get locks that are exclusive with each other (writer locks), as the default might be shared locks (reader locks which only conflict with a writer lock but not with each other). Not sure which behavior is the default.

Comment: @user1686 I consulted the manual on Debian. `-x` is the default.

Comment: @user1686 "it may be still initializing, it may be waiting for the lock timeout, or it may be about to exit..." but what about `flock` succeding on acquiring the lock and leaving the `while` loop check, and letting the work/log happen? Could I have coded it wrong in some non-clear way?

Comment: I think tho the biggest problem is it not failing on my notebook (I made it run for a few hours), this means the script may not fail to other ppl and I cant prove my point/problem, as it may be exclusive to a defective (or low quality) hardware :/

Comment: Analysis of `lslock` output. `/home/myUser/bin/flock.tst.sh (deleted)` is a different file (different inode) than `/home/myUser/bin/flock.tst.sh`, so these are independent locks. The asterisk in `WRITE*` means the process is blocked and waiting for the lock (see `man 8 lslocks`). The question is: why is `/home/myUser/bin/flock.tst.sh (deleted)` there? It apparently interferes. Is it some *old* script that runs in the background all the time maybe? Removing the executable did not stop it (and this is normal).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes, I was about to research it, that (deleted) is interfering. It is working as a simultaneous lock on my script. It counts up to 60s to finish, and the problem happened at second 50, so the script was still alive for more 10s. Any idea what I could do to grant the lock will be exclusive? as aparently `flock` is succeeding to acquire the lock, while there was still 10s of an active lock by another process. "different file (different inode)" why it happened and how to fix it? I will update the question later after I eat something, thx!

Comment: A process that holds the lock on a deleted file will not prevent you from obtaining a lock on *another* file with the same path. Why was `/home/myUser/bin/flock.tst.sh` deleted and (I guess) recreated?

Comment: It was surely not deleted by me, but to be 100% sure I could make it root owned (also the whole path tree) and read-only and run it again! unless it is related to file descriptor, but I dont know how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hypothesis: just before it happened you saved the script. Your editor saved a copy and then moved the copy to the original path. See [how Vim does this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/625673/108618) and [why](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37177/108618).

In effect the old lock was still held on the old file (inode). This showed as `…/flock.tst.sh (deleted)` in the output of `lslocks`. But `flock`s your script (another instance of it?) kept spawning use the path. When the path started pointing to another inode, some new `flock` was allowed to acquire a new lock. This showed as `…/flock.tst.sh` in the output of `lslocks`.

The two locks were independent, they couldn't block each other because they used *different* files. Flock worked as designed.

I can actually recreate your result by running two instances of the script (so one gets the lock and another keeps trying to get it) and then opening it with `vim` and writing (`:w`) right away. Alternatively:

```
cp flock.tst.sh foo
mv foo flock.tst.sh
```

Comment: I use geany. As soon I hit Ctrl+s the "problem" happened as many times I did it! Good the problem was between my keyboard and my chair, and not in my hardware, thx vm! xD. Also I never edited it on notebook!